# How to add new field to struct column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql, field

I have a dataframe with something like this `df.printSchema`:

```
root
|-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- geoip: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- location: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- lat: float (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- lon: float (nullable = true)
```

I know that for example with `df = df.withColumn("error", lit(null).cast(StringType))` I can add a `null` field called `error` of type `string` right under the `root`. How could I add the same field under the `geoip` struct, or under the `location` struct?

I have also tried `df = df.withColumn("geoip.error", lit(null).cast(StringType))` with no luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR** You have to map the rows in a Dataset *somehow*.

### map Operator (the most flexible)

Use [map](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@map[U](func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]) operation which gives you the most flexibility since you're in the total control of the final structure of the rows.

> **map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]** (Scala-specific) Returns a new Dataset that contains the result of applying `func` to each element.

Your case would then look as follows:

```
// Create a sample dataset to work with
scala> val df = Seq("timestamp").
  toDF("ts").
  withColumn("geoip", struct(lit("Warsaw") as "city", lit("Europe") as "continent"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts: string, geoip: struct<city: string, continent: string>]

scala> df.show
+---------+---------------+
|       ts|          geoip|
+---------+---------------+
|timestamp|[Warsaw,Europe]|
+---------+---------------+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- continent: string (nullable = false)

val newDF = df.
  as[(String, (String, String))].  // <-- convert to typed Dataset as it makes map easier
  map { case (ts, (city, continent)) =>
    (ts, (city, continent, "New field with some value")) }. // <-- add new column
  toDF("timestamp", "geoip") // <-- name the top-level fields

scala> newDF.printSchema
root
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
```

That's not pretty as you lost the names of the columns.

Let's define the schema with the proper names. That's where you can use [StructType](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) with [StructFields](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField) (you could also use a set of case classes, but I leave it to you as a home exercise).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val geoIP = StructType(
  $"city".string ::
  $"continent".string ::
  $"new_field".string ::
  Nil
)
val mySchema = StructType(
  $"timestamp".string ::
  $"geoip".struct(geoIP) ::
  Nil
)

scala> mySchema.printTreeString
root
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- new_field: string (nullable = true)
```

Apply the new schema for proper names.

```
val properNamesDF = spark.createDataFrame(newDF.rdd, mySchema)
scala> properNamesDF.show(truncate = false)
+---------+-----------------------------------------+
|timestamp|geoip                                    |
+---------+-----------------------------------------+
|timestamp|[Warsaw,Europe,New field with some value]|
+---------+-----------------------------------------+
```

#### How to add field to "struct of a struct"

If you feel fairly adventurous, you may want to play with `StructType` as a collection type and re-shape it using Scala's Collection API and copy constructor.

It does not really matter how deep you want to go and what level of "struct of a struct" you want to modify. Just consider a StructType as a collection of StructFields that may in turn be StructTypes.

```
val oldSchema = newDF.schema
val names = Seq("city", "continent", "new_field")
val geoipFields = oldSchema("geoip").
  dataType.
  asInstanceOf[StructType].
  zip(names).
  map { case (field, name) => field.copy(name = name) }
val myNewSchema = StructType(
  $"timestamp".string :: 
  $"geoip".struct(StructType(geoipFields)) :: Nil)
val properNamesDF = spark.createDataFrame(newDF.rdd, myNewSchema)
scala> properNamesDF.printSchema
root
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- new_field: string (nullable = true)
```

### withColumn Operator with struct Function

You could use [withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@withColumn(colName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) operator with [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@struct(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function.

> **withColumn(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame** Returns a new Dataset by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.
>
> **struct(cols: Column*): Column** Creates a new struct column.

The code could look as follows:

```
val anotherNewDF = df.
  withColumn("geoip", // <-- use the same column name so you hide the existing one
    struct(
      $"geoip.city", // <-- reference existing column to copy the values
      $"geoip.continent",
      lit("new value") as "new_field")) // <-- new field with fixed value

scala> anotherNewDF.printSchema
root
 |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- geoip: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- city: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- continent: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- new_field: string (nullable = false)
```

As per a comment from [@shj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499483/shj), you can use a wildcard to avoid re-listing the columns, which makes it pretty flexible, e.g.

```
val anotherNewDF = df
  .withColumn("geoip",
    struct(
      $"geoip.*", // <-- the wildcard here
      lit("new value") as "new_field"))
```

Answer (score 5):

**Spark 3.1+**

```scala
col("geoip").withField("error", lit(null).cast("string"))
```

---

Example input:

```scala
val df = Seq(("Vilnius", "Europe", 1, 1)).toDF("city", "continent", "lat", "lon")
         .withColumn("location", struct("lat", "lon").as("location"))
         .select(struct("city", "continent", "location").as("geoip"))
df.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- geoip: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- location: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- lat: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- lon: integer (nullable = false)
```

Example #1

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("geoip", col("geoip").withField("error", lit(null).cast("string")))
df2.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- geoip: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- location: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- lat: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- lon: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- error: string (nullable = true)
```

Example #2

```scala
val df3 = df2.withColumn("geoip", col("geoip").withField("location.error", lit(null).cast("string")))
df3.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- geoip: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- continent: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- location: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- lat: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- lon: integer (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- error: string (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- error: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: col("geoip").withField("location.error"....  gives an error:
"error: value withField is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column"

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply do:

```
df = df.withColumn("goip", struct($"geoip.*", lit("This is fine.").alias("error")))
```

That adds an "error" field to the "geoip" struct.

Answer (score -1):

The same way but by referencing the column.

```
df = df("location").withColumn("error", lit(null).cast(StringType))
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! I tried this but gives me the error `error: value withColumn is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. I have Spark 1.5.2 with Scala 2.10